# How do you determine a set that a series converges on absolutely uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Alright, so I know that there are a bunch of tests to figure out whether a series is convergent/the types of convergence, but how do you find the specific set that a particular series is convergent on? I was checking the Weierstrass M-test, but I don't think that specifies the interval?

Also, there is a specific series that I'm looking at right now, but I want to figure out if there's a general way to do this, so I'll add an image of the series later if anyone wants to look at it.

EDIT: This is the series that I'm looking at right now:
[image: series]

Comment: How are you defining this "the specific set"? For example, there are instances where uniform convergence holds on any interval of the form $[0, a]$, but doesn't hold on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: I guess the hand-wavy answer to your question is that determining intervals where uniform convergence holds is situation-dependent.

Comment: @angryavian so there's no general way to figure it out, given any series? 
Also, I've added the series that I'm trying to figure out a set for, so I'm hoping that helps? 
Also, yeah, I meant like any set that pertains to a given series. (I feel like the way I'm wording it makes it more confusing but I hope you get what I'm asking?)

Comment: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^n}{\sqrt{n}}=\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)$$ is defined when $\frac{x}{x+1}<1\to x>-1$. Li is the polylogarithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }f_n(x)$$
Ratio test
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left|\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}\right|=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left|\frac{\sqrt{n} x}{\sqrt{n+1} (x+1)}\right|=\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|$$
converges if $$\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|<1\to x>-\frac12$$
In that interval it is absolutely convergent.

---

Edit

As $|f_n(x)|=\lim_{x\to+\infty} f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ Weierstrasss M-Test cannot be applied.
but the given series converges uniformly on any interval $[x_1,x_2];\; \left(x_1>-\frac12\right)$ because the
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^n$$
converges.

It converges because for $x>-\frac12$ we have $\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|<1$ that means that there exists a $z>1$ such that $\left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|<\frac{1}{z}$, therefore

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \left|\frac{x}{x+1}\right|^n<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}z^n}<\frac{1}{z^n}$$
which converges

Comment: Oh okay, this was really helpful! This doesn't have anything to do with the polyalgorithm thing you mentioned before, right? Also, how would this show uniform convergence as well?

Comment: @Applesauce44 I edited my answer because I forgot the uniform convergence

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using the polylogarithm though? I checked with the Weierstrass test, but choosing the function to be less than $$\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)}$$ doesn't conclude convergence....

Comment: @Applesauce44 $\sum \frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{n}}$ converges because $\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{2^n}$. That's enough. You don't have to specify the sum.

Comment: @Applesauce44 I made a mistake. I am sorry. I edited my answer and now it's OK.